# axios not getting data on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm trying to fetch data on the first render and then do some calculations with it and display it in a table. But what happens is after first render the State of `fetchArray` is an empty array, if I click the Update Table button, it fetches only the first part, which are the user orders:

[image: After first render]

After the first render, when I click the update table button it renders again and I get only the data from database fetch:

[image: After update table click]

Now after the third click everything finally renders:

[image: After 2nd click]

These are the files being used:

**OrderList.js**

```js
export default function OrderList() {
  
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
  const [fetchArray, setFetchArray] = useState([]);
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context)
  const [authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useState(true)

  const orders = []

    //get the logged in user from local storage then get user ID
    const getAuthUser = () =>{
      try{
          const userId = localStorage.getItem('user')
          const foo = JSON.parse(userId)
          const id = foo.auth.user
          //console.log(id)
          if(!id || id == null){
            console.log(userId)
            setAuthenticatedUser(false)
          }else{
              return id
          }

      }catch(e){
          console.log(e)
          console.log("No auth")
      }
  }

  const deleteOrder = async(row) =>{

    const order = {
      ticker: row.ticker,
      amount: row.amount,
      price: row.price,
      date: row.date,
      comments: row.comments
    }

    console.log("Deleted " + JSON.stringify(order))

    /*try{
      await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8081/api/auth/delete-order/${getAuthUser()}`, order)
      .then((res) =>{
        console.log("deleted " + JSON.stringify(res))
        setIsDelete(true)
      }).catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
      })
    }catch(e){
      console.log("inside deleteORder: " + e)
    }*/

  }

  //Calculates the profit or loss for a single position
  const profitLossCalculator = (price, currentPrice, quantity) => {
    let profitLoss = 0;

    if (currentPrice) {
      profitLoss = (currentPrice - price) * quantity;
    }
    return profitLoss.toFixed(2)
  }

  //Calculates the profit or loss for the whole portfolio
  const profitLossTotalCalculator = (fetchArray) => {
    let profitLossTotal = 0;

    fetchArray.forEach((stock) => {
        if (!isNaN(Number(stock.profitLoss))) {
            profitLossTotal += Number(stock.profitLoss);
        }
    });

    return profitLossTotal.toFixed(2);
  }

  const getOrders = ()=>{

    setErrorMsg("")
    setFetchArray([])
  
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/auth/user/${getAuthUser()}`)
        .then(response => {
            if(response){
                setUserInfo(response.data)
                console.log(userInfo)

            }else if(!response.data[orders] < 1){
              setErrorMsg("No orders to display. Add orders and try again")
            }
        }).then((() =>{
          if(fetchArray.length > 0){
            console.log("jeje")
          }
        }))
        .catch(e =>{
            setErrorMsg("Something went wrong while trying to get your orders")
            console.log(errorMsg + e)
        })
        setLoading(false)

      const foo = userInfo.orders
      for(var i in foo){
        const fee = foo[i]
        setFetchArray(prev =>[...prev, fee])
      }

      if(fetchArray.length > 0){
        stockFetcher(fetchArray, setFetchArray, profitLossCalculator)
      }
  }

    

  useEffect(() =>{
    getOrders()
  }, [])







  //if data is being fetched
  if(loading) {
    return (
      <>
      <p>Data is loading...</p>
      </>)
}
  
  return (
    <div>
      {authenticatedUser ? (
        <div style={{display: "flex", width: "150vh", minHeight: "100vh"}}>
        <div style={{display: "inline-block", width: "150vh"}}>
          <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{maxWidth: 1200, padding: 6, margin: "auto", marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10}}>
            <h1 style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Your orders, {userInfo.firstName}</h1>
            <div> 
              <h4>
                Total profit: <p style={{color: `${profitLossTotalCalculator(fetchArray) <= 0 ? "red" : "green"}`}}>{profitLossTotalCalculator(fetchArray)}€</p>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <Table sx={{padding: 20, minHeight: 350,}} aria-label="simple table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow sx={{maxHeight: 600}}>
                  <TableCell></TableCell>
                  <TableCell>Ticker</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Price(€)</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Date</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Current price</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Profit/Loss</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">Comments</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {fetchArray ? (fetchArray.map((row) => (
                    <TableRow
                    key={row.ticker}
                    sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                  >
                  <TableCell>
                    <Button onClick={() => deleteOrder(row)}>
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </Button>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                      {row.ticker}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.price}€</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.amount}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.date}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.currentPrice}€</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right" style={{color: `${row.profitLoss <= 0 ? "red" : "green"}`}}>
                    {row.profitLoss}€
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{row.comments}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))) : (
                  <span style={{color: "red"}}>Couldn't retrieve data</span>
                )}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
          <button onClick={() => getOrders()}>Update table</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      ) : (
        <block>
        <h1>You are not logged in!</h1>
        <a href="/login">Go back</a>
        </block>
    )}
      
  </div>
  )
}
```

**StockFetcher.js**

Here happens all the external API fetches and calculations

```
//Function which fetches the current prices and updates our state with current prices and profit/loss
const stockFetcher = (stocks, setStocks, profitLossCalculator) => {
    stocks.forEach(async(stock) => {
        console.log(stock)
        try {
            const ticker = stock.ticker
            const response = await axios.get(`${STOCK_API_GLOBAL}&symbol=${ticker}&apikey=${TOKEN}`)
            const returnedData = await response.data;
            console.log(returnedData)

            const yesterday = new Date()
            yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate())
            const time = yesterday.toISOString().slice(0, 17).replace("T", " ").concat("00")


            const currentPrice = returnedData['Global Quote']['05. price']

            const profitLoss = profitLossCalculator(
                stock.price,
                currentPrice,
                stock.amount
            );

            const stockWithPrice = {
                ...stock,
                currentPrice: currentPrice,
                profitLoss,
            };

            const indexOfStock = stocks.indexOf(stock);
            setStocks((stocks) => [
                ...stocks.slice(0, indexOfStock),
                stockWithPrice,
                ...stocks.slice(indexOfStock + 1),
            ]);
        } catch (error) {
            /*The option how to handle the error is totally up to you. 
                Ideally, you can send notification to the user */
            console.log("error with stockFetcher: " + error);
        }
    });

    return setStocks
};

export default stockFetcher;
```

I guess my question is that why doesn't the `useState` set itself inside the fetch. If it would be set during the first render then all would be fine.

Comment: Fetching remote data is asynchronous and doesn't block rendering, so if you call `setState` and then do some async stuff (like fetching data with axios) which will call `setState` again react will render in between those calls to `setState`. If you only want your app to rerender after all fetching is done you need to await all results first and only then call `setState` with all the aggregated results of your fetches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a UseEffect with the state that its going to update

Comment: Can you please provide a code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thats the thing. If I put the state which gets bounced around in the code (fetchArray), then it goes into to an endless loop of rendering because the fetchArray gets set in the getOrders function. So everytime getOrders gets rendered it will set fetchArray and if the fetchArray state is the dependency of useEffect is won't stop re-rendering since it gets changed all the time